# How can I override allauth's SignupForm class so that I can remove the emailfield's label?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-allauth

[Screenshot of the rendered form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT793.png)

I have done all necessary imports and the code is fine but the emailfield's label still shows up even after setting it to false.

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = False
        self.fields['password1'].label = False
        self.fields['password2'].label = False
        self.fields['email'].label = False

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        user.save(commit=False)
```

This is the allauth/accounts/forms.py

```
class BaseSignupForm(_base_signup_form_class()):
    username = forms.CharField(label=_("Username"),
                           min_length=app_settings.USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(
                               attrs={'placeholder':
                                      _('Username'),
                                      'autofocus': 'autofocus'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'type': 'email',
           'placeholder': _('E-mail address')}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        email_required = kwargs.pop('email_required',
                                app_settings.EMAIL_REQUIRED)
        self.username_required = kwargs.pop('username_required',
                                        app_settings.USERNAME_REQUIRED)
        super(BaseSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        username_field = self.fields['username']
        username_field.max_length = get_username_max_length()
        username_field.validators.append(
            validators.MaxLengthValidator(username_field.max_length))

        # field order may contain additional fields from our base class,
        # so take proper care when reordering...
        field_order = ['email', 'username']
        merged_field_order = list(self.fields.keys())
        if email_required:
            self.fields["email"].label = ugettext("E-mail")
            self.fields["email"].required = True
        else:
            self.fields["email"].label = ugettext("E-mail (optional)")
            self.fields["email"].required = False
            self.fields["email"].widget.is_required = False
            if self.username_required:
                field_order = ['username', 'email']...
```

I believe the "if email_required" to be the problem. Any help to show what I'm doing wrong will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to render as I wanted. I used:

```
self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_show_labels = False
```

and a {% crispy form %} tag.

Comment: Hi, I've tried using Django-Crispy-Forms but the error messages do not show up(e.g. for required fields). Did you face the same problem?

Comment: Hi, are you using allauth? If not, crispy forms' form_show_labels shouldn't hide your error messages

Comment: Yes, I'm using Crispy forms to remove the labels like what you are doing here. The labels are removed, but the error messages do not work. I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrongly. Can you help me do a quick check on mycode [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931540/validation-error-not-showing-on-form)? Thks.

Comment: Hmm I have pretty much the same code and the errors are showing up fine for me. Crispy forms should have its form_show_errors attribute set to True by default but try stating it explicitly and see if that helps